# What does this XML mean in context with database

Tags: xml, database

This is the edit to my original post which was considered unclear.
I was asked to "recreate a database from the XML schema" below. I was given no other information as this was part of a test of my programming skills in order to apply for a job.
The XML was an example of a file to be read and then later added to the database(another part of the test).
Using Dataset.ReadXML() I was able to read the XML into A DataSet and infer the table structure and
relations between the tables.
There are 4 tables, Inquiry, Order, Client and Contact.
Inquiry has a 1 to many relation to Order, a 1 to 1 with CLient and Client has a 1 to 1 with Contact.
Hope this helps anyone else who may encounter something simmilar.

```
<Inquiry>
  <Number>1</Number>
  <DateTime>20090611132245</DateTime>
  <Active>True</Active>

<Order>
  <Type>AB</Type>
  <Number>1234</Number>
  <DateTime>20090519121315</DateTime>
</Order>

<Order>
  <Type>BC</Type>
  <Number>1235</Number>
  <DateTime>20090619111234</DateTime>
</Order>

<Client>
  <Name>Qwest</Name>
    <Contact>
      <Name>D Thomas</Name>
      <TelephoneNumber>1234567</TelephoneNumber>
    </Contact>
</Client>
</Inquiry>
```

Comment: What's the question again?

Comment: The semantics of any XML element and attribute names are defined purely on a business logic level. They could literally mean anything. Without any additional information - as much as I would like to help - it's pure guesswork.

Comment: I assume this code represents results from a query joining 3 tables, Inquiry, Order and Client where an Inquiry is linked to a Client and a list of their orders.

Comment: the database must match the XML schema

Comment: OK figured it out.
You can create an an XSD schema from the XML using sequel management studio.
Then found a utility "xsdtdb" that creates the database from the XSD, had to edit the table definitions though as some of the types were not what i wanted eg tinyint instead of int.
http://xsd2db.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this XML the result of a query selecting Inquiry with Order and Client connected with foreign keys?

It might be. On the other hand, it might just be some XML that someone typed in a text editor. How could we possibly know? As for its meaning, XML means nothing unless you've got access to documentation telling you what it means. We can guess what meaning a rational person creating this XML would be trying to convey, but that's only a guess. If we know English, we can surmise that it represents an enquiry from a client, or perhaps to a client, and we might expect the relationship between clients and enquiries to be one-to-many; but that's all inference and depends totally on the use of well-known English words as element names.

Comment: And the fact that Jim Garrison has guessed different semantics for the XML fragment just goes to prove my point.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be, as you guessed, three tables `Inquiry`, `Order` and `Client`. While you can infer a foreign-key relation ship between `Order` and `Client`, there is not enough information to infer anything about a relationship from `Inquiry` to the other tables.

`Inquiry` seems represent a query of the database, which could involve more tables.  The "relationship" such as it is would be represented by the query criteria, i.e. the SQL statement for the query.  It is a meta-relationship between the user doing the querying and the various tables queried.  Representing that meta-relationship is one level "up" from relationships represented by tables and foreign keys.